# How to resampling OHLC Data in 15-Minute Intervals with Market Hours Consideration and Non-Repainting

Tags: python, pandas

I have OHLC (Open, High, Low, Close) data at a 3-minute timeframe, and I want to convert it into 15-minute OHLC intervals while considering market hours (from 9:15 AM to 3:30 PM). I'm using the `resample()` function from the Pandas library to achieve this. However, I'm facing two challenges:

1. Market Hours: The `resample()` function doesn't take into account the market hours, and I want to ensure that the resampled data falls within the specified trading hours.

For example, in the df below, the data is resampled with NaN because market is closed at that time. These values causes incorrect values of supertrend.

[image]

[image]

2. Non-repainting: I want to prevent the resampled signals from "repainting." In other words, if the 15-minute period is not complete (e.g., the current time is 10:18 AM, and the 15-minute interval is from 10:15 AM to 10:30 AM), I want to return the previous entry (e.g., at 10:14 AM) from the original data frame.

Here's the code I'm using:

```py
prices_data_x_min_df = TechnicalHelper.resample_df(prices_data_df=prices_data_df,
                                                   resample_period=self.supertrend_period_config)
nifty_prices_data_x_min_df = TechnicalHelper.resample_df(prices_data_df=nifty_prices_data_df,
                                                         resample_period=self.supertrend_period_config)
```

And here's the `resample_df` function:

```py
@staticmethod
def resample_df(prices_data_df: pd.DataFrame, resample_period: str):
    prices_data_df.set_index('record_ts', inplace=True)
    market_open = pd.Timestamp('9:15:00').time()
    market_close = pd.Timestamp('15:30:00').time()

    market_hours_data_df = prices_data_df.between_time(market_open, market_close)

    prices_data_x_min_df = market_hours_data_df.resample(resample_period).agg({
        'open': 'first',
        'high': 'max',
        'low': 'min',
        'close': 'last',
        'volume': 'sum'
    }, origin='start')

    prices_data_x_min_df.dropna(inplace=True)
    return prices_data_x_min_df
```

I'm looking for a solution to address these two challenges while resampling the data. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please read [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). "please help me" is [not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question); we don't write code to specification. [You are expected to study the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) ahead of time; think of logical steps to solve the problem; figure out exactly where you are stuck, and be able to show exact input and output.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @itprorh66. I am not sure what additional information I could have given - I have written the exact scenario with the code and output, along with where I am stuck. Please let me know what can be improved - will update the question

Comment: @Shikhar Vaish does my answer work for you or could you provide feedback?

Answer (score 0):

First we want to generate a `list` of time intervals so that we can group indexes if they fall within them. So for example, indexes that are between 9:30am and 9:45am with the current date (i.e. in case you plug in multiple data across multiple days):

```
[9, 30, 9, 45, '2023-09-27']
```

So we get a start hour and start minute (`[9, 30]`) and a stop hour and stop minute (`[9, 45]`), and if the stop hour is the next hour (e.g. 10:00am) we're going to use the same hour but minute `60` (i.e. `[9, 60]`).

```
def get_candlesticks(df, candlestick_size_in_minutes=30, last_trading_hour=16, first_trading_hour=9, first_trading_minute=30):
    '''returns a list of pairs of time stamps as integers [hour (start), minute (start), next hour (stop), next minute (stop)] from 9:30am up to (but not including) 4:00pm grouped by the candlestick_size_in_minutes parameter'''
    __hour = df.hour.iloc[0]
    def round_minute_down(__minute, candlestick_size_in_minutes):
        candlesticks = np.arange(0, 60 + candlestick_size_in_minutes, candlestick_size_in_minutes).astype(int)
        first_candlestick = np.where(np.abs(candlesticks - __minute) == np.min(np.abs(candlesticks - __minute)))
        if candlesticks[first_candlestick] > __minute:
            first_candlestick[0][0] -= 1
        return candlesticks[first_candlestick[0][0]]

    __minute = round_minute_down(df.minute.iloc[0], candlestick_size_in_minutes)
    __date = 0
    candlesticks = [[__hour, __minute, __hour + 1 if __minute + candlestick_size_in_minutes > 60 else __hour, min(__minute + candlestick_size_in_minutes, 60), np.unique(np.array(df.date))[__date]]]
    for _ in range(int((390 - candlestick_size_in_minutes) / candlestick_size_in_minutes)*np.unique(np.array(df.date)).shape[0]):
        __minute += candlestick_size_in_minutes
        if __minute >= 60:
            __minute -= 60
            __hour += 1
        if __hour == last_trading_hour:
            __hour = first_trading_hour
            __minute = first_trading_minute
            __date += 1
        if __date >= np.unique(np.array(df.date)).shape[0] - 1 and candlesticks[-1][1] <= df.minute.iloc[-1] < candlesticks[-1][3] and candlesticks[-1][0] == df.hour.iloc[-1] and candlesticks[-1][4] == df.date.iloc[-1]:
            return candlesticks
        candlesticks.append([__hour, __minute, __hour + 1 if __minute + candlestick_size_in_minutes > 60 else __hour, min(__minute + candlestick_size_in_minutes, 60), df.date.iloc[0] if np.unique(np.array(df.date)).shape[0] == 1 else np.unique(np.array(df.date))[min(__date, np.unique(np.array(df.date)).shape[0] - 1)]])
    return candlesticks
```

Then all we have to do it iterate over those time intervals; in order to vectorize the process, we can `def`ine a function that returns `True` for the indexes in the `df` that meet our time interval conditions and input it into `numpy`'s `where()` function:

```
def is_a_candlestick(df_hours, df_minutes, _hour, _minute, _next_hour, _next_minute, df_date, _date):
    '''returns True for timestamps ([hour, minute]) that match the correct candlestick; conditions vectorized for numpy.where() function'''
    if all([df_date == _date, df_hours == _hour, _hour == _next_hour, df_minutes >= _minute, df_minutes < _next_minute]) or all([df_date == _date, df_hours == _hour, _hour != _next_hour, df_minutes >= _minute, df_minutes < _next_minute if _minute < _next_minute else True]) or all([df_date == _date, df_hours == _next_hour, _next_minute != 60, df_minutes < _next_minute, df_minutes >= _minute if _minute < _next_minute else True]):
        return True

is_a_candlestick = np.vectorize(is_a_candlestick)
candlesticks = get_candlesticks(df, candlestick_size_in_minutes)
y = np.zeros((len(candlesticks), 4)).astype(float)
for candlestick, (_hour, _minute, _next_hour, _next_minute, _date) in enumerate(candlesticks):
    indexes = np.where(is_a_candlestick(np.array(df.hour), np.array(df.minute), _hour, _minute, _next_hour, _next_minute, np.array(df.date), _date))
    y[candlestick, :] = np.array([df.open.iloc[indexes].iloc[0], np.max(df.high.iloc[indexes]), np.min(df.low.iloc[indexes]), df.close.iloc[indexes].iloc[-1]])
```

And this is much easier when we initially create/modify our timestamps and dates in the `df` so that `'hour'` and `'minute'` are integers in separate columns:

```
def parse_date_from_timestamp(timestamp):
    return timestamp[:timestamp.find(' ')]

def parse_time_from_timestamp(timestamp):
    return timestamp[timestamp.find(' ') + 1:timestamp.find('-4:') - 5]

df['date'] = df.timestamp.map(parse_date_from_timestamp)
df['timestamp'] = df.timestamp.map(parse_time_from_timestamp)

def get_hour(timestamp):
    return int(timestamp[:2])

def get_minute(timestamp):
    return int(timestamp[3:5])

df['hour'] = df.timestamp.map(get_hour)
df['minute'] = df.timestamp.map(get_minute)
```

Altogether, we generate our start and stop times `list`, iterate and fill a `numpy` matrix of zeros, and then return the data as a dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
def candlesticks_function(df, candlestick_size_in_minutes=30):
    def get_candlesticks(df, candlestick_size_in_minutes=30, last_trading_hour=16, first_trading_hour=9, first_trading_minute=30):
        '''returns a list of pairs of time stamps as integers [hour (start), minute (start), next hour (stop), next minute (stop)] from 9:30am up to (but not including) 4:00pm grouped by the candlestick_size_in_minutes parameter'''
        __hour = df.hour.iloc[0]
        def round_minute_down(__minute, candlestick_size_in_minutes):
            candlesticks = np.arange(0, 60 + candlestick_size_in_minutes, candlestick_size_in_minutes).astype(int)
            first_candlestick = np.where(np.abs(candlesticks - __minute) == np.min(np.abs(candlesticks - __minute)))
            if candlesticks[first_candlestick] > __minute:
                first_candlestick[0][0] -= 1
            return candlesticks[first_candlestick[0][0]]

        __minute = round_minute_down(df.minute.iloc[0], candlestick_size_in_minutes)
        __date = 0
        candlesticks = [[__hour, __minute, __hour + 1 if __minute + candlestick_size_in_minutes > 60 else __hour, min(__minute + candlestick_size_in_minutes, 60), np.unique(np.array(df.date))[__date]]]
        for _ in range(int((390 - candlestick_size_in_minutes) / candlestick_size_in_minutes)*np.unique(np.array(df.date)).shape[0]):
            __minute += candlestick_size_in_minutes
            if __minute >= 60:
                __minute -= 60
                __hour += 1
            if __hour == last_trading_hour:
                __hour = first_trading_hour
                __minute = first_trading_minute
                __date += 1
            if __date >= np.unique(np.array(df.date)).shape[0] - 1 and candlesticks[-1][1] <= df.minute.iloc[-1] < candlesticks[-1][3] and candlesticks[-1][0] == df.hour.iloc[-1] and candlesticks[-1][4] == df.date.iloc[-1]:
                return candlesticks
            candlesticks.append([__hour, __minute, __hour + 1 if __minute + candlestick_size_in_minutes > 60 else __hour, min(__minute + candlestick_size_in_minutes, 60), df.date.iloc[0] if np.unique(np.array(df.date)).shape[0] == 1 else np.unique(np.array(df.date))[min(__date, np.unique(np.array(df.date)).shape[0] - 1)]])
        return candlesticks

    def is_a_candlestick(df_hours, df_minutes, _hour, _minute, _next_hour, _next_minute, df_date, _date):
        '''returns True for timestamps ([hour, minute]) that match the correct candlestick; conditions vectorized for numpy.where() function'''
        if all([df_date == _date, df_hours == _hour, _hour == _next_hour, df_minutes >= _minute, df_minutes < _next_minute]) or all([df_date == _date, df_hours == _hour, _hour != _next_hour, df_minutes >= _minute, df_minutes < _next_minute if _minute < _next_minute else True]) or all([df_date == _date, df_hours == _next_hour, _next_minute != 60, df_minutes < _next_minute, df_minutes >= _minute if _minute < _next_minute else True]):
            return True

    is_a_candlestick = np.vectorize(is_a_candlestick)
    candlesticks = get_candlesticks(df, candlestick_size_in_minutes)
    y = np.zeros((len(candlesticks), 4)).astype(float)
    for candlestick, (_hour, _minute, _next_hour, _next_minute, _date) in enumerate(candlesticks):
        indexes = np.where(is_a_candlestick(np.array(df.hour), np.array(df.minute), _hour, _minute, _next_hour, _next_minute, np.array(df.date), _date))
        y[candlestick, :] = np.array([df.open.iloc[indexes].iloc[0], np.max(df.high.iloc[indexes]), np.min(df.low.iloc[indexes]), df.close.iloc[indexes].iloc[-1]])
    return pd.DataFrame({'open': y[:, 0], 'high': y[:, 1], 'low': y[:, 2], 'close': y[:, 3]})


stock_symbol = 'SPY'
_date = '2023-09-27'

file_name = "/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/DATA_FOLDERS/DATA_FRAMES/" + stock_symbol + '_' + _date + '.csv'

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(file_name)

def parse_date_from_timestamp(timestamp):
    return timestamp[:timestamp.find(' ')]

def parse_time_from_timestamp(timestamp):
    return timestamp[timestamp.find(' ') + 1:timestamp.find('-4:') - 5]

df['date'] = df.timestamp.map(parse_date_from_timestamp)
df['timestamp'] = df.timestamp.map(parse_time_from_timestamp)

def get_hour(timestamp):
    return int(timestamp[:2])

def get_minute(timestamp):
    return int(timestamp[3:5])

df['hour'] = df.timestamp.map(get_hour)
df['minute'] = df.timestamp.map(get_minute)

y = candlesticks_function(df, candlestick_size_in_minutes=15)
print(y)
```

Outputs:

```
      open    high     low   close
0   427.11  427.67  426.65  426.90
1   426.89  427.65  426.82  426.87
2   426.88  427.12  425.86  426.06
3   426.07  427.03  425.85  426.74
4   426.74  426.93  426.25  426.34
5   426.33  426.50  425.01  425.15
6   425.15  426.05  425.05  425.87
7   425.87  426.06  425.45  425.91
8   425.93  426.12  425.04  425.05
9   425.06  425.12  424.59  424.87
10  424.85  424.92  423.97  424.11
11  424.10  424.17  423.76  423.93
12  423.90  424.68  423.90  424.44
13  424.44  424.88  423.97  424.05
14  424.05  424.68  423.99  424.04
15  424.05  424.12  422.76  422.84
16  422.83  423.12  422.29  422.61
17  422.57  423.32  422.53  423.16
18  423.19  423.33  422.61  422.90
19  422.90  424.39  422.89  424.37
20  424.37  426.22  424.26  426.03
21  426.02  426.33  425.53  425.96
22  425.96  427.54  425.69  427.13
23  427.13  427.13  426.31  426.77
24  426.76  426.78  424.87  424.92
25  424.91  426.00  424.86  425.73
```

Though you can input `15` into the starting minute parameter, I'm not sure why'd you want to start at 9:15am (market hours are 9:30am to 4:00pm), and the functions I provided also account for missing minutes (i.e. first timestamp at 10:18am with 15-minute candlesticks groups it into the 10:15am to 10:30am candlestick) instead of dropping values or inputting the previous value (i.e. 10:14am). If you can explain why then I'll modify my answer but generally speaking it wouldn't make sense to drop the delayed values and use the previous entry as the timestamps don't align (i.e. so that would mean your data is intentionally misleading/incorrect) and no one does that.